# image_tag doesn't display external images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails 4 application and I'm using image_tags throughout the application, 
I'm trying to show images on twitter. If I view the source the img src tag seems fine and I can view the image using the url that's in the img src tag.

Images in my assets folder display fine.

Any ideas what's causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, Use

`<%= image_tag "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DYKjGQLW4AAh9fI.jpg" %>`

Is this something you were asking?

Comment: That's code I have, it was working at one point then it just stopped working. 
I tried your line of code & the same thing happened.

Comment: That's unusual. Maybe checking your logs for any errors may help. BTW which rails 4 version are you using?

Comment: It looks like it's adblocker issue, I recently moved over to firefox quantum and by default it has tracking protection on. I disabled this and it worked. Any thoughts on how to get around this for users using the app?